# Can anyone tell me why this is entering a new line

Tags: vb.net

I am concatenating a variable onto a path(string), i'm using a message box to display this for testing purposes, I can see that the variable is starting on a new line, which in turn when i try to open the file it doesn't recognize that the file exist...

```
Dim Path As String = "C:\Users\stefan\Desktop\Uni Work\Year 4\Projects\Project Selection\Project\Project\bin\Debug\"
    Shapetext = clickedShapes.Item(nextShape).Text.ToString.Substring(0, clickedShapes.Item(nextShape).Text.IndexOf(" "))

                        MsgBox(Path + Shapetext + ".txt")
```

can any1 help me out here?

Comment: You're sure the messagebox doesn't just display the whole thing in two lines because it's a bit long? Else, what is in Item(nextShape) exactly?

Comment: Item(nextShape) this is the text within a clicked shape in visio, there is only a small amount text in ShapeText.txt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to:

- Remove the MsgBox and replace with
  System.Diagnostics.Debug.Writeline(Path + Shapetext + ".txt")
- Put a breakpoint on that line and run the debugger until the point.
- Take note of the output in the output window.
- Check if the file really exist in the output folder

At this point will be obvious what's wrong. Or file doesn't exist, or your string concat fails for some reason.

Comment: Hmm nothing is being outputted to the debug output window?

Comment: One more step in the debugger (F8 if I remember well for VB.NET or F11 in C#)

Comment: hmm, there's a definite new line there, would i be right in saying that office uses the same ascii characters are the same?

Comment: Somewhere this newline thing goes into `clickedShapes.Item(nextShape).Text`. (By the way, probably Text is already a string, no need to call ToString again)

Comment: ok thanks, i used substring to take off the first value which was the newline :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

On your final output string, you could always use something like

```
string.replace(vbCrLf, "")
```

or

```
string.replace(vbCr, "")
```